# Android Programming Book (Jelly Bean)

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean

I would like to ask if anyone knows of a good beginner's book/tutorial (*or website*) for Android. Preferably, presents examples suited for Jelly Bean.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an Android developer, his first reference is [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/index.html).
Besides, there are several tutorial sites from which these two I found very useful and easy to learn.

1. [www.vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials.html)
2. [www.androidhive.info](http://www.androidhive.info/)